# How to make a temporary name of a variable when using pipelines

Tags: r, dataframe, pipeline, simplify

I have a following code and I want R to give me back just the data.frame but it still gives back even the other value. Any idea how to simplify it?

INPUT:

```
new_guy_A <- assign('age_A', median(data_kids[gender=='muz',]$age)) %>%
   data.frame(age = age_A,
              height = age_A + rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = std),
              gender = 'muz')
```

OUTPUT:

```
        .      age   height gender
1 12.33566 12.33566 13.95272    muz
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data_kids)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data_kids, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

The question's code seems to be after the following.

```
library(dplyr)

std <- 1

data_kids %>%
  filter(gender == 'muz') %>%
  summarise(age_A = median(age),
            height = age_A + rnorm(1, sd = std),
            gender = first(gender))
#  age_A   height gender
#1    14 14.42912    muz
```

**Test data.**

```
set.seed(1234)
data_kids <- data.frame(age = sample(10:18, 4),
                        gender = rep(c('muz', 'baz'), 2))
```